# How to generate a html.Table with a for loop?

Tags: for-loop, iteration, typeerror, dashboard, plotly-dash

I'm trying to generate a html.Table in my dash app. The table should have 2 columns and max. 5 rows. The first one showing the customer names and the second one their total revenue for the year.

```
def generate_html_table(max_rows=5):
    return html.Div([
                html.Div(html.Table(id='Customer Top'
                    #header
                    [html.Tr(html.Th())]
                +
                    #body
                    [html.Tr([
                        html.Td(html.A(
                        topCustomers.iloc[i]['Customer'],
                            topCustomers.iloc[i]['Total Including Tax']
                        ))
                    ])
                     for i in range(min(len(topCustomers),max_rows))
                    ]
                ))
    ])
```

When I run the app I get a **TypeError: string indices must be integers**

UPDATE:

I fixed the above mentioned error by changing my code to this:

```
def generate_html_table(max_rows=5):
    return html.Div([
                html.Div(html.Table(
                    [html.Tr(html.Th()),
                    html.Tbody(html.Tr([
                        html.Td(html.A(
                        topCustomers.iloc[i]['Customer'],
                        topCustomers.iloc[i]['Total Including Tax']
                        ))
                    ])                      for i in range(min(len(topCustomers),max_rows))
                              )
                    ]
                ), id='Top Customer')
    ])
```

But now the dash app won't load the layout. I'm not quite sure what the problem is, but it tells me **TypeError: Object of type generator is not JSON serializable**

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Your return statement is returning a generator, because of the list comprehension you've used. Instead, build the table and put it in a variable, then return that variable. You may need to call `list()` on it to have it build the whole thing before outputting it.

You could also restructure the loop in a more basic way such as:

```py
for x in 'abc':
   do_stuff()
```

and within that loop build the table, only returning it after the loop completes.

Edit:
I used a dummy dataframe and was able to get the page to load data with this:

```py
def generate_html_table(max_rows=5):
    rows = []
    for i in range(min(len(topCustomers), max_rows)):
        rows.append(html.Tr([
            html.Td(html.A([
                topCustomers.iloc[i]['Customer'],
                topCustomers.iloc[i]['Total Including Tax']
            ], id=str(i))
        ]))

    return html.Div([
        html.Div(html.Table(
            [
                html.Tr(html.Th()),
                html.Tbody(rows),
            ]
        ), id='Top Customer')
    ])
```

Comment: Hi coralvanda, thx so much for your answer! You may have noticed that I'm not experienced with python and I guess this is a very complicated task for me. Your first suggestion didn't work, although I'm not sure I did it right. Your second suggestions at least returned the layout but the table didn't  show up on the screen.

Comment: `def generate_html_table(max_rows=5):
    
for i in range(min(len(topCustomers),max_rows)):
        html.Div([
                html.Div(html.Table(
                    [html.Tr(html.Th()),
                    html.Tbody(html.Tr([
                        html.Td([
                            html.A(topCustomers.iloc[i]['Customer']),
                            html.A(topCustomers.iloc[i]['Total Including Tax'])])
                    ])
                              )
                    ]
                ), id='Top Customer')
    ])
        
    return generate_html_table`